# export map state as JSON: Web_Map_as_JSON

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson, export, json

Is there a way to export the current map state as a JSON object, mostly named **Web_Map_as_JSON**. 
The JSON specification should be like [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ExportWebMap_specification/0154000004w8000000/).

In other words, it would be convenient to have a function for the Map object, like myMap.Web_Map_as_JSON() that would provide the current state of the MAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not directly available through the API. The PrintTask can be used to get the Web_Map_as_JSON.

```
map.on("load", function(){

  require(["esri/tasks/PrintTask", "dojo/_base/json"], function(PrintTask,  JSON){

    var printTask = new PrintTask();   

    var Web_Map_as_JSON = JSON.toJson(printTask._getPrintDefinition(map));

  });

});
```

Comment: this will not work in JS API 3.20 , _getPrintDefinition needs two parameters, 1 ) map and 2 ) print parameters , code should be like this ,                      
 var Web_Map_as_JSON = JSON.toJson(printTask._getPrintDefinition(this.currentMap,printParams));

Comment: @AhammadaliPK confirmed working in JS API 3.28

Comment: @AhammadaliPK Thanks for the statement. You are right this worked for me when using 3.11 but now that I need to upgrade to a newer API version I have to adapt it as you suggest.

Comment: For your information,
For JS API < 3.14 you need var Web_Map_as_JSON = JSON.toJson(printTask._getPrintDefinition(map)). While, 
for JS API >= 3.14   you need JSON.toJson(printTask._getPrintDefinition(this.currentMap,printParams));

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this before...and although I do not know how to export JSON in the exact web map spec that you referenced, you can come close using the [Item Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Item_Data/02r300000075000000/) operation of the REST API which can exports [Web Map data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Web_map_data/02r30000003p000000/).  This might have the information that you require (or not).

As I mentioned, the JSON object returned using this operation is not the same as the [ExportWebMap specification](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/ExportWebMap_specification/02r3000001mz000000/). See [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Web_map_format/02r30000004n000000/) page for more information on Web Map formats (see note at bottom).