# Get JSON WebMap from ArcGIS JavaScript API Map object

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to get a WebMap object (as JSON) from a JavaScript Map object in the ArcGIS JavaScript API. Is there any way to do this within the API, without using ArcGIS.com? Ideally something like:

```
var webMapAsJSON = map.toWebMap();
```

[From the "Export Web Map Task" documentation](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task) in the REST API, there's this line that suggests it should exist:

> "The ArcGIS web APIs (for JavaScript, Flex, Silverlight, etc.) allow
>   developers to easily get this JSON string from the map."

However, I don't see anything in the Map object or elsewhere in the API that would do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have answered this question in an [earlier post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113465/export-map-state-as-json-web-map-as-json).

You are headed in the right direction. It is the PrintTask module that has this undocumented capability.