# Is there a way to export and import again all Map at once?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson, kml, export

I have a OpenLayer3 map with some arbitrary layers I can choose at runtime. Layers may come from external WMS services or internal PostgreSQL GIS tables or even from drawn features.

Now, I need a way to export all this stuff to reproduce this same situation again later (on same server). Including zoom level and viewport.

Is there a way to do this (KML, GeoJSON, etc)?

Comment: You'll have to use custom code for this; It can write the layers, symbology and extent etc to a JSON object, and save it on your server. When the app loads, it would read this JSON object and recreate the map.

Comment: Hum... Ok. A lot of work.... Now I see my question is a dup: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113465/export-map-state-as-json-web-map-as-json?rq=1

Comment: That is for the ESRI JavaScript API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your needs are stepping up from simple viewer to managing maps across sessions you should either build your own, or look into something offering that functionality out of the box. MapStore 2  for example offers this functionality (among several others) and it's open source:
http://geosolutions-it.github.io/MapStore2/

There are other projects building on top of OL or Leaflet, but I don't remember an open sources one that allows saving maps as you require.

Comment: Thanks for MapStore 2. Very good framework. But I don't have time to learn about it and rebuild all my application. I'll try to find a way by myself or just store the layers names, zoom and extent for now. I'll accept because anyone with a little good will can find the answer in the MapStore source code.